# Can I use IPython in an embedded interactive Python console?

Tags: python, console

I use the following snippet to drop into a Python shell mid-program. This works fine, but I only get the standard console. Is there a way to do the same but using the [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/) shell?

```
import code

class EmbeddedConsole(code.InteractiveConsole):
    def start(self):
        try:
                self.interact("Debug console starting...")
        except:
                print("Debug console closing...")

def print_names():
    print(adam)
    print(bob)

adam = "I am Adam"
bob = "I am Bob"

print_names()
console = EmbeddedConsole(locals())
console.start()
print_names()
```

Comment: Could you please mark Dereck's answer as it is most current now?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer by f3lix is no longer valid it seems, I was able to find this however:

At the top of your python script:

```
from IPython import embed
```

Wherever you want to spin up a console:

```
embed()
```

Answer (score 2):

[Embedding IPython](http://www.ifi.uio.no/~inf3330/scripting/doc/python/ipython/node9.html) might be interesting for you.

Mininum of code to run IPython in your app:

```
from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed
ipshell = IPShellEmbed()
ipshell() # this call anywhere in your program will start IPython
```

Comment: See below, now there is an embed function from IPython can be used instead.