# Embedded interactive shell in IPython

Tags: python, embed, ipython

Before switching to IPython v0.11 (using Python 2.6.1), it was possible to embed an interactive IPython shell using for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499705/can-i-use-ipython-in-an-embedded-interactive-python-console), e.g.

```
from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed
ipshell = IPShellEmbed()
ipshell() # this call anywhere in your program will start IPython
```

"The embedded shell has been refactored into a truly standalone subclass of *InteractiveShell* called *InteractiveShellEmbed*. All embedding logic has been taken out of the base class and put into the embedded subclass" (see [here](http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/manual/html/whatsnew/development.html) and [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/closed#issue/286)).

The way I understand it you should now be able to simply start a console by

```
import IPython
IPython.embed()
```

However, this raises

> TraitError: The 'exit_msg' trait of an InteractiveShellEmbed instance must be a string,    but a value of u''  was specified.

If we pass a string for `exit_msg` by

```
IPython.embed(exit_msg='Whatever')
```

Then it raises a different error

> AttributeError: 'InteractiveShellEmbed' object has no attribute 'set_completer'

Did anybody else encounter this problem? Otherwise this might be a bug since it is a developer version after all.

Answer (score 10):

These days (3.0+) all you need to do is:

```
from IPython import embed; embed()
```

If you mean embedding another IPython shell in IPython (recursively), there was a long time that this was not supported, but that problem was patched last year.

Answer (score 3):

There are [specific  instructions](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Cookbook%3a-Updating-code-for-use-with-IPython-0.11-and-later) on the github wiki:

```
from IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp import TerminalIPythonApp
app = TerminalIPythonApp.instance()
app.initialize(argv=[]) # argv=[] instructs IPython to ignore sys.argv
app.start()
```